# How to combine many multitail parameters?

Tags: parameter, multitail

The .multitailrc file contains a color scheme called amir_log, which I load using `multitail -cS amir_log ~/wildfly/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/log/server.log`

But there are ANSI color codes being displayed as `^{[32m`, for example. That is corrected with `-cT ANSI`.

The file can be opened with `multitail -cT ANSI -cS amir_log ~/wildfly/wildfly-8.2.1.Final/standalone/log/server.log` or `-cT ANSI` at the end, but only the first parameter is detected.